# Ssh pubkey permission denied even all rights are correct

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have such output below for testing ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org. Pubkey successfully added to bitbucket, directory and other rights are correct 100%.

```
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.226.0482edc app-127
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.226.0482edc app-127
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

As you see private key is found and rsa signature is correct. But still have permission denied.

Comment: I broke my head until understood what is that mean.
`Host bitbucket.org`  
`    Hostname bitbucket.org`  
    User git  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa  
    IdentitiesOnly yes  
`

You see, it should be correct. Until googling I found god-saving option `PubKeyAuthentication yes`. By default it is on but in the bottom of .ssh/config it was disabled
`Host *
    PubkeyAuthentication no`
Why? I don't know the reason but once I add _Yes_ is become working ok.

Comment: `debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa type -1` this does not seem right.

Comment: @Jakuje does not matter I think. It does not apply to the end result even all work ok.

Comment: Since the client is not able to recognize your authentication key, it probably matters.